# Advises about Spring Framework Implementation

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have a Windows server with  SQL Server /IIS running on it, and the for the next application we're planning to create a Java Web App. I've found Spring Framework / Hibernate combo as a compelling option, but I can see that only in my development phase it consumes a lot of memory and processor and I got many PerGem Exceptions, Of course that I've tuned the Java Opts for the increase of Pergem Space,etc but what I can see is that in my dev environment (NetBeans / Maven) it gets really slow, to wait for Tomcat recognize XMLs, redeploy the app, it is more slow than the classic servlet MVC aproach,

My question is: ¿In a server with modest hardware/memory config, with services already running is the Spring / Hibernate combo play well or better I go for other modest way(JSF or Servlets JSPs? ¿Opinions, experiences?, For now there's no budget to buy a new server.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC vs JSF should not make a big difference in memory consumption. Replacing hibernate by spring-jdbc might safe you a bit, but how going out of PermGem with a normal Spring/Hibernate app seems strange. Which version of tomcat are you using?
And are you only redeploying/ hot swapping, or sometimes also restarting? 
Tomcat has had memory issues with hot-swapping for a long time.